# Get string or array from Enum

Tags: java, enums

I have `enum`

```
public enum Test {
 ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR
}
```

And I search easy way to get contained elements to `String` or to `Array` as we can get it from `Arrays` like in example below

```
String[] tab = {"one", "two", "three"};

Arrays.toString(tab);
```

**HOW TO get `String` from all `enums`?**

Comment: **1.** It's unclear what you're asking. **2.** Please post your attempts *after* clarifying your question.

Comment: You can use Test.values() which returns array of Test

Comment: What You don't understand in `And I search easy way to get contained elements to String or to Array as we can get it from Arrays` ? All downvoters please comment why give minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Arrays.toString(Test.values());
```

where `Test` is your enum class. The `values()` method returns an array of the enum's constants.